# Assigning colors to a d3.js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to create a color-coded bar chart using d3. I am SO CLOSE. Here's my bl.ocks chart:

http://bl.ocks.org/sconnors37/b99070b055f125c9dff1/1cb53954be3f20e3c4492066eccd749b5cf04bbe

What I'm trying to do is assign color values based on the "teams" field in my .tsv file. So grey for Mercedes, red for Ferrari, etc. I have the teams in the var color domain and the colors in the var color range, and I'm pulling var color into the bar attrib.

For some reason though, the entire chart is just taking on the first item in the range - I changed it from grey to red just to see if that was what was going on, and it is.

So! How do I get the rest of my colors to pull through onto the bar chart? Help me, stackoverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: you have 8 values in the domain, 9 in the range, and also when you append the rectangles the first selectAll should be selectAll("rect") and not '.bars'

Comment: try with the RGB values of the colors, instead of names.

Comment: @tomtomtom actually there's nine values in each, you have to scroll to the right to see them all. Ill try changing the selectAll and see if that works, thanks!

Comment: @tomtom The `selectAll(".bar")` is correct. The `rect` added are classed with `bar`. Making it `selectAll("rect")` would be making things worse because it could select some other `rect` elements which aren't part of the chart.

Comment: yup I saw your reply and that's almost 100% what was going wrong. I just thought that maybe the selection could somehow be bugged and consider the whole class as one element and so return just the grey.
In his/her case tho there are no other rect elements so it's not that much of a problem I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.tsv` file the last column `team` is not separated from the previous column by a tab, but rather through two spaces. If you look at the `data` passed to the `d3.tsv` callback I think you will find that you have one `date  team` column instead of a `date` and `team` column.

This means that the field `d.team` is `undefined` and `ordinal(undefined)` will just return the first value from the range.

Comment: hi @cyon, thanks that's exactly what was happening. So I've fixed that and all the bars just disappeared. Guess more troubleshooting is needed. Here's the most recent edit: http://bl.ocks.org/sconnors37/b99070b055f125c9dff1/29317f83a65f3a117473aca6273257c5a44a7a0a

Comment: ETA: there were double spaces in the rest of the data as well! I feel like an idiot but I'm glad my code was right, haha. Thank you!